python set of dictionaryies only shows last value
the following python code only shows last value, why not all dictionaries? (no for loops or anything)
it is driving my crazy as i cant see if updates are properly done
my_constraint = {
    'constraint_class': 'FixedCombinations',
    'table_name': 'DIM_SITE', # for multi table synthesizers
    'constraint_parameters': {
        'column_names': ['SITE_NAME2', 'COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'LANDCODE', 'REGION' ]
    },
    'constraint_class': 'FixedCombinations',
    'table_name': 'REPORT_ASSET_PROBLEMS_ULT_AUTOMATE', # for multi table synthesizers
    'constraint_parameters': {
        'column_names': ['ASSET_TYPE', 'ASSET_NAME', 'PROBLEM', 'SOLUTION']
    },
    'constraint_class': 'FixedCombinations',
    'table_name': 'REPORT_ASSET_STATUS_REPORT', # for multi table synthesizers
    'constraint_parameters': {
        'column_names': ['ASSET_TYPE', 'ASSET_NAME', 'PROBLEM', 'SOLUTION']
    },
    'constraint_class': 'FixedCombinations',
    'table_name': 'SITE', # for multi table synthesizers
    'constraint_parameters': {
        'column_names': ['LANDCODE', 'COUNTRY', 'CITY', 'REGION']
    },
    'constraint_class': 'FixedCombinations',
    'table_name': '', # for multi table synthesizers
    'constraint_parameters': {
        'column_names': ['LEVEL', 'COMPONENT', 'COMPONENT_NAME', 'KPI', 'CWR', 'CR']
    }
}

a = str(my_constraint)
print(a)


Each time the key 'table_name':  occurs, it overwrites value mapped to the previous one. Did you want a list of dicts?

You don't have a set of dictionaries. You have a single dictionary. You're trying to use duplicate keys, but keys must be unique.

You can't put dictionaries in a set, but you can put them in a list.

A dictionary will not have duplicate keys. In your case, one of the keys (for example constraint_class) is being assigned a value. Only the last value assigned to the key is kept in the dictionary.
You might want to create a list of dictionaries. An example would be :
a_list = [{"key":"value1"}, {"key":"value2"}, {"key":"value2"}]


my god how stupid, just a late one i guess, looked at the wrong part of the documentation! thanks for the swift answers!
